# How to retrieve the postID in a "image_send_to_editor" hook function?

Tags: posts, images, filters, hooks, editor

Here is my function:

```
function insert_img_rel_attrib( $html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url  )
{
  $postID = ???
  $rel = "<a rel='shadowbox[".$postID."]'";
  if ($url) {$html = str_replace("<a",$rel,$html);}
  return $html;
}
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'insert_img_rel_attrib', 10, 6 );
```

How do I get the current post ID? I've tried the obvious, `global $wp_query;
$postID = $wp_query->post->ID;` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work within your function:

```
get_post_field( 'post_parent', $id )
```

Comment: This seems to get the id of the post which originally uploaded the image, not the current post being edited.

Answer (score 0):

Your global should work, what happens when you echo `$postID` ( you should probably use a more unique name here).

You can also try,

```
global $post;
$Your_Post_ID = $post->ID;
```

I am not very familiar with this hook though, you might have to use `wpdb`.

Comment: This hook is being used inside the editor, fyi.

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall, the global `$post` isn't set in the thickbox. You can check the contents of the global `$_REQUEST` though, and retrieve it from there (assuming that the editor is being called from a post editing screen and not through the media manager or some other location).